# C++ program to print counting numbers

Tags: c++, terminal

In case the title is not precisely revealing what I want to do, the following is my problem.

I want to write a c++ program in a Linux or Mac terminal to print numbers that keeps counting from 1, 2, 3 ... at the same position under a command line mode. For example, it is like displaying the number of percentage when your work is progressing(e.g. downloading something, installing software...).

I wrote a simple for-loop to print numbers and use `usleep(1000);` for a delay of 1 second before printing next number. Then I use `cout << "\b";` trying to move cursor back to display coming number at the same position. However I fail to create the effect that I want, the numbers are printed in a line.

I am not a skillful c++ programmer and know very limited on programming in a terminal environment. Can anyone help to give me hint or sample code for this function? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in Linux Terminal you can also use the following code,

```
system("clear");
cout<<"\b";    
cout<<Your_Number;

// Repeat this in a loop and call the delay function
```

Comment: Tried it and only saw the last number appearing on top of the screen. Not seeing the effect of counting numbers.

Comment: Call the delay function to add delay.

Comment: I also tried varying the sleeping time for slowing down the counting, but the outcome is the same. Only saw the last number on top with more waiting time for the last number to appear. Before that, the screen is blank.

Comment: [Screen Shot](https://plus.google.com/photos/109630056848880246701/albums/5886340184718104129/5886340190469296786#photos/109630056848880246701/albums/5886340184718104129/5886340190469296786?pid=5886340190469296786&oid=109630056848880246701) - Left is the code, right is the result. Still fail to print counting number

Comment: This is actually not a good way as clear just shifted previously printed things on terminal by a fixed offset upward

Answer (score 0):

This works in terminal for me (am using linux)
    #include
    #include
    using namespace std;

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        int i;
        for(i=1;i<100;i++)
        {
                cout<<"\b\b\b"<<i;
                cout.flush();
                sleep(1);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: This will print upto 99 without a newline(you can print 100 as well and can also decide what to be done at specific number by using if else)

Comment: It does work. "cout.flush()" is key to successfully create the running effect. Thanks!